# SELECT entire rows with max date in a GROUP BY

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I realize this has been asked before, but the answers i've seen never contemplate the case where the dates are exactly the same.

I have the following table with money transfers.

[image: table]

I need the **TRANSFER_ID** of the latest transfer for each group of **CORPORATION + ACCOUNT**

This is my current query:

```
SELECT  tt.transfer_id,
        tt.corporation,
        tt.account,
        tt.date
    FROM Transfers tt INNER JOIN
        (SELECT t.corporation, 
                t.account, 
                MAX(t.date) AS day_last_transfer
            FROM Transfers t
        GROUP BY t.corporation, t.account) j
    ON  tt.corporation = j.corporation
    AND tt.account = j.account
    AND tt.date = j.day_last_transfer
```

The issue is that I sometimes get 2 or 3 records for the same **CORPORATION + ACCOUNT** with diferent transfer_id's when doing the **inner join** because of the dates being exactly the same.

Lastly, I have to use MS ACCESS to perform this query

Comment: Please add some sample records that will show the undesired behavior, and the expected result from these records. [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Can't depend on the max transfer_id (by alpha sort) for each corporation/account to be the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then select *Max* (or *Min*) id:

```
SELECT 
    Max(tt.transfer_id) As last_transfer_id,
    tt.corporation,
    tt.account,
    tt.date
FROM 
    Transfers tt 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT t.corporation, 
        t.account, 
        MAX(t.date) AS day_last_transfer
    FROM Transfers t
    GROUP BY t.corporation, t.account) j
    ON  tt.corporation = j.corporation
    AND tt.account = j.account
    AND tt.date = j.day_last_transfer

GROUP BY
    tt.corporation,
    tt.account,
    tt.date
```